# Transferring projects between Mac and Windows

Tags: github, flutter

I have a Flutter project I created with Android Studio in Windows. I tried to copy, compile, and run it on iOS (via a Mac with XCode, obviously). I tried GitHub to copy the project between OS's as well as just zipping the project in Windows & unzipping in OSX.

I had an issue with the error

> /bin/sh: D:\Flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: No
>   such file or directory /bin/sh:
>   D:\Flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: No such file
>   or directory

Even a newbie like me recognizes there's no `D:\` drive to recognize in OSX. Are there any best practices or suggestions I should know about to minimize the likelihood of these kinds of issues? In OSX I will be compiling *only* for iOS.

Comment: You need to set up your Dart sdk path in Android Studio.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Thanks for your response. Paths set up properly for Android Studio in Windows, not using it in OSX. I'm just using XCode+flutter on the Mac, and it's set up properly. I can run some simple apps on the Mac, deploying to both the simulator and a physical device.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get you before, do you mean you aren't using Android Studio on your macOS? If yes, what does it mean `I'm just using XCode+flutter on the Mac`?

Comment: I installed (only) the Flutter SDK and XCode on the Mac. No Android Studio on the Mac.

Comment: I assume that you have run flutter pub upgrade after the copy.

Comment: Actually, I eventually realized on my own that was the key issue, that I hadn’t run pub update. If you post that, though, I will be happy to mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @chris-reynolds (and I) noted above, it turned out the issue was that I had not gotten the application's dependencies after cloning it from GitHub. So, to summarize, what I should have done & will do in the future is:

1. Write code (on Windows) and push it to GitHub
2. Clone my app on MacOS

> `$ git clone https://github.com/myUserId/myApp.git`
>   `$ cd myApp`

3. Make sure I've downloaded the app's dependencies

> `$ flutter pub get`

4. [Modify the iOS version of the app as necessary]
5. Build it (`$ flutter build ios`) or run it (`$ flutter run`)!